# JSON.simple library saying unexpected character (<)

Tags: java, json

Java class

```
package voteHandler.Org.RSPSVote;
/* 
 * Author: Sieu Phan
 * Website: RSPS Vote
 * Data: 5/7/2014
 * Version: 1.1
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL; 
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONValue;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class voteHandler {
    private static String SERVER = "";
    private static String API_KEY = "";
    public voteHandler(String SERVER_TO_SET, String API_KEY_TO_SET)
    {
        SERVER = SERVER_TO_SET;
        API_KEY = API_KEY_TO_SET;
    }
    /*
        Sends a GET request to RSPS Vote API.
        RETURNS: a boolean
    */
    public static boolean authenticate(String AUTH)
    {
        String url = generateURL(AUTH);
        try {
            String getJSON = IOUtils.toString(new URL(url));
            JSONObject message = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(getJSON);
            String messageData = (String) message.get("MESSAGE");
            System.out.println(messageData);
            int responseData = Integer.parseInt((String) message.get("RESPONSE"));
            System.out.println(responseData);              
            if(responseData == 5)
                return true;  
        } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;           
    }   

    public static boolean getReward(String AUTH)
    {
        String url = generateURL(AUTH);
        return false;
    }
    /*
        Generates the url to the API 
        RETURNS: a String
    */
    private static String generateURL(String AUTH)
    {
        String URL = "http://rspsvote.com/widget/api.php?" 
                        + "action=check" 
                        + "&server=" + SERVER 
                        + "&key=" + API_KEY 
                        + "&auth=" + AUTH;
        return URL;
    }   
}
```

Testing class

```
import voteHandler.Org.RSPSVote.voteHandler;


public class testing {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        voteHandler vote = new voteHandler("l6DZw", "ELWXQ-MI4BC-3K1RT-VUKPT-DGL2U");
        vote.authenticate("Ptpz1n");
    }
}
```

what's wrong with this JSON format being returned from the site?

http://rspsvote.com/widget/api.php?key=ELWXQ-MI4BC-3K1RT-VUKPT-DGL2U&action=check&auth=Ptpz1n&server=l6DZw

Also this is the error I get from eclipse:

```
Unexpected character (<) at position 63.
    at org.json.simple.parser.Yylex.yylex(Yylex.java:610)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.nextToken(JSONParser.java:269)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:118)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:81)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:75)
    at org.json.simple.JSONValue.parseWithException(JSONValue.java:78)
    at voteHandler.Org.RSPSVote.voteHandler.authenticate(voteHandler.java:34)
    at testing.main(testing.java:8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's wrong with this JSON format being returned from the site?

It doesn't return JSON. The response's content type is `text/html` and the body contains

```
{"RESPONSE":"7","MESSAGE":"AUTHENTICATION WAS UNSUCCESSFUL."}
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

You'll need to get rid of the XML or stop parsing after the JSON.